# change the style of img inside a div tag

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

How to change that with javascript, I know in css its:

```
.test img {display:block;}
```

but in javascript I only know this:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.display="block";
```

thats obviously the whole div tag , not the img.

Comment: Your element has a class, not an ID ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using an ID `"test"`, you can do this.

```
document.getElementById("test")
        .getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.display="block";
```

This uses `getElementsByTagName` which returns a collection of the images found. The `[0]` grabs the image at index `0` (the first image), and then applies the style.

If you have a class `"test"`, you can do this, but it won't work in IE7 and below:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".test > img");

for( var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
    imgs[i].style.display="block";
}
```

For the widest browser compatibility, you can do this:

```
function getElementsByClassName( root, clss ) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        result;
    clss = " " + clss + " ";
    for( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
        if( (" " + elems[ i ].className + " ").indexOf( clss ) > -1 ) {
            result.push( elems[i] );
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var tests = getElementsByClassName( document, "test" );

for( var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++ ) {
    var img = tests[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    if( img ) {
         img.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Comment: or just `$('.test img').css('display', 'block')` in jQuery ;-)

Comment: thats only using id "test", its not possible to do with class "test", right? as there are many "test" divs on the page...

Comment: Oops, yes I didn't notice you were using a class. You can use `getElementsByClassName`, but it isn't supported in IE8 and lower. It also returns a collection, so you'd need to iterate the collection.

Comment: Alnitak , that looks awesome:) But I need it without jquery.

Comment: @N_F_S yup, it's sad how hard DOM stuff seems without jQuery :(

Comment: @N_F_S: I updated to use `querySelectorAll`, which has support in IE8 and above.

Comment: @N_F_S you need a `[0]` suffix on the `getElementsByClassName()` result too, and an error check in case it doesn't actually appear!

Comment: RightSaidFred, thats for all images it finds inside a div, right? But if theres only one image, which would be [0], the code would be the same?

Comment: RightSaidFred, I prefer your first solution, I am not worried about ie8 and lower, its for a background style, not that iportant and wont break any design if it doesnt show up,  thanks a bunch!